# how to get direct URL from insta share url

Tags: instagram-api

I am making a Telegram Bot witch take from user share URL Link from Instagram and pass to user photo or video of that link.
I have got media_id and photo from this Instagram API

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/

But when I want to get direct URL of video by media id with below API

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I get Error that media id is invalid I think this is because my access token is in sandbox mode 
I do not want to take access token of users I just want to take direct URL of the share URL

what should I do know ?

## instagram

Answer (score 0):

Simple add `/media/` to URL:

before: 
http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/

after:
http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/media/

Comment: its hust send thumbnail of the post ! but doesnt give the video or albums ! how can we get them?

Comment: get page and extract <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="...video url here..." />

Comment: thanks alot , but when I'm trying to get the page by file_get_contents the return is empty! in another word i cant get the source of the instagram post page , is there any way to do it ?

Comment: use curl with cookies and useragent. check how it looks in Chrome developer console

Comment: your answer was very great thanx, now do have any idea to get story and user profile photo from instagram ?